# Move the car with inertia

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am trying to move the car with inertia without any physics. I am using View-based application in Objective C.
Is it possible to do something like this? My task is:
I touch the car and move it left, when the touch ended method is completed car should continue moving with inertia.

Comment: [Yes it is possible](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is momentum rather than inertia...

Comment: 'I am trying to move the car with inertia without any physics' - you may find this difficult..

Comment: If you don't want to use physics, just create a simple linear or quadratic equation which the speed of the car slows down as more time passes.

Comment: yes maybe it is momentum. I don't know. : ( any idea?

Comment: inertia is the tendency of a body to resist acceleration (that includes deceleration which is simply acceleration in the opposite direction to the velocity). So, yes, inertia is the right word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything?

If you don't want to do it with physics you'll have a hard time trying to get it to do what you want it to do realistically. At the very least you'll need

```
v = u - at
```

where:

```
v is the new speed, 
u is the initial speed 
t is the time and 
a is the deceleration
```

It's the deceleration that you will need to come up with a figure for by yourself.